# Проблемы с пагинацией/коллбеками в aiogram3

Tags: python, aiogram-3.x

Пишу бота на `aiogram3` для администрирования сайта. С помощью бота можно получать/изменять/удалять/добавлять пользователей и новости. Бэк написан на `Django` с использованием `SQLLite` и `Rest-framework`. Пагинация данных происходит на стороне бэка с помощью класса `Paginator`. В боте уже использую `Router`, так как хендлеры находятся в других директориях и файлах.

**Проблема:**
При выводе всех новостей/пользователей есть возможность переходить по страницам с помощью Inline-кнопок. При получении всех новостей callback от кнопок работает нормально, но при получении всех пользователей callback не отрабатывает. В консоли выводится лог: `INFO:aiogram.event:Update id=769373400 is handled. Duration 0 ms by bot id=6151615027`.

Как мне кажется, проблема появляется из-за того, что роутеры имеют однонаправленную связь и, так как у меня кнопки и для новостей и для пользователей одни и те же, программа просто не попадает в следующий роутер.

Код с подключением роутеров в *`main.py`*:

```
dp.include_routers(bot_commands.bot_commands_router)
dp.include_routers(get_news_handlers.get_news_router)
dp.include_routers(get_users_handlers.get_users_router)
```

Код с пагинацией:

```
@database_sync_to_async
def pagination(page_number, model):
    get_model = model
    paginator = Paginator(get_model, 5)
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    page_previous = page_obj.has_previous()
    page_next = page_obj.has_next()
    all_pages = paginator.num_pages

    return list(page_obj), page_previous, all_pages, page_next
```

Код для отлова callback после нажатия на кнопку:

```
@get_users_router.callback_query(lambda c: True)
async def get_users_callback(callback: CallbackQuery,
                             state: FSMContext):

    data = await state.get_data()

    if 'to users' in callback.data:
        page = int(callback.data.split(' ')[2])
        await state.update_data(page=page)
        paginator, has_previous_page, all_pages, has_next_page = await pagination(page_number=page,
                                                                                  model=data['all_users'])

        response_text_users = []
        for user in paginator:
            response_text_users.append(
                f'<b>id пользователя:</b> {user.pk}\n'
                f'<b>Имя пользователя:</b> {user.username}\n'
            )

        keyboard = get_users_keyboards(page=page,
                                       has_previous_page=has_previous_page,
                                       all_pages=all_pages,
                                       has_next_page=has_next_page,
                                       )

        await callback.message.edit_text(text=''.join(response_text_users), reply_markup=keyboard)
        await state.set_state(GlobalState.waiting_for_user)
```

код для вывода клавиатуры:

```
def get_users_keyboards(page, has_previous_page, all_pages, has_next_page):
    
    next_page = page + 1 if has_next_page else page
    previous_page = page - 1 if has_previous_page else page

    buttons = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton(text='⏪', callback_data=f'to users {1}'),
            InlineKeyboardButton(text='◀', callback_data=f'to users {previous_page}'),
            InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'{page}/{all_pages}', callback_data=f'all users'),
            InlineKeyboardButton(text='▶', callback_data=f'to users {next_page}'),
            InlineKeyboardButton(text='⏩', callback_data=f'to users {all_pages}')
        ]
    ]
    if not has_previous_page:
        del buttons[0][:2]
    if not has_next_page:
        del buttons[0][-2:]
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=buttons)

    return keyboard
```

Для новостей callback и клавиатура аналогичны. Изначально, функция вывода клавиатуры была одна на оба callback, но после того, как столкнулся с проблемой, решил разбить её на две, думая, что это поможет. Увы, проблема осталась.
[image: Вывод всех новостей с успешным переходом на вторую страницу]
[image: Вывод всех пользователей с неработающим переходом на следующие страницы]

Буду рад любой подсказке. Заранее спасибо за ваше время!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил следующим способом:

В callback от Inline-кнопок заменил *lambda c: True* на *F.data.startswith('to users')* для пользователей и *F.data.startswith('to news')* для новостей

Было:

```
@get_users_router.callback_query(lambda c: True)
async def get_users_callback(callback: CallbackQuery,
                             state: FSMContext):

    data = await state.get_data()

    if 'to users' in callback.data:
        page = int(callback.data.split(' ')[2])
        await state.update_data(page=page)
        paginator, has_previous_page, all_pages, has_next_page = await pagination(page_number=page,
                                                                                  model=data['all_users'])

        response_text_users = []
        for user in paginator:
            response_text_users.append(
                f'<b>id пользователя:</b> {user.pk}\n'
                f'<b>Имя пользователя:</b> {user.username}\n'
            )

        keyboard = get_users_keyboards(page=page,
                                       has_previous_page=has_previous_page,
                                       all_pages=all_pages,
                                       has_next_page=has_next_page,
                                       )

        await callback.message.edit_text(text=''.join(response_text_users), reply_markup=keyboard)
        await state.set_state(GlobalState.waiting_for_user)
```

Стало:

```
@get_users_router.callback_query(F.data.startswith('to users'))
async def get_users_callback(callback: CallbackQuery,
                             state: FSMContext):

    data = await state.get_data()

    page = int(callback.data.split(' ')[2])
    await state.update_data(page=page)
    paginator, has_previous_page, all_pages, has_next_page = await pagination(page_number=page,
                                                                              model=data['all_users'])

    response_text_users = []
    for user in paginator:
        response_text_users.append(
            f'<b>id пользователя:</b> {user.pk}\n'
            f'<b>Имя пользователя:</b> {user.username}\n'
        )

    keyboard = get_keyboards(page=page,
                             has_previous_page=has_previous_page,
                             all_pages=all_pages,
                             has_next_page=has_next_page,
                             command='users'
                             )

    await callback.message.edit_text(text=''.join(response_text_users), reply_markup=keyboard)
    await state.set_state(GlobalState.waiting_for_user)
```